# SSO Website-Network with Facebook Login

Tags: facebook, single-sign-on

### I am currently developing a SSO website-network.

It has a few websites wich are unfortunately all separate domains like:

- domain.de
- domain-specials.de
- domain-otherthings.de
- somethingelse.de

I have managed to create a [SSO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on) using JSONP / Ajax, so when you login to any of the sites you are signed on into the others as well.

Now i need to implement a "[login with facebook](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/)" feature that works with the current SSO.

The problem here is that a facebook app can only have one root domain to work with so if you try to use the Facebook-App on another website you mostly get security errors.

I tried the Facebook Client-Side Authentication which of course doesn't work on any other site than the one I created the Facebook-App for:

```
API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
```

I also tried using a channel file in the FB.init which is currently used on all websites:

```
FB.init({
    appId      : '1234567890', // app id
    channelUrl : 'http://www.domain.de/channel.html', // fqd-path to channel file
    status     : true, // check login status
    cookie     : true, // allow the server to access the session
    xfbml      : true, // parse XFBML
    oauth      : true // ?
});
```

Now I am currently experimenting with the Server-Side Authentication but I am still unsure if there isn't a better way to solve this problem since it forces me to redirect to the domain I used in the Facebook-App.
The main problem here being the user flow.

**The client flow is quite nice**

1. Click login with Facebook
2. Facebook popup
3. Click yes or no
4. Done!

**While the server flow is not so fluid**

1. Click login with Facebook
2. Redirect to Facebook
3. Click yes or no
4. Redirect to root domain
5. Somehow redirect to originating domain
6. Done!

I have also thought about creating an app for every single site; but that is just stupid.

So, if anyone knows a better solution to this problem or if anything needs more clarification, please let me know.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I had to create a little workaround. By using a designated landing script for all logins I was able to redirect the users back to the refering page.

This Facebook link redirects to http://mydomain.de/fb_connect/1/

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=[your_app_id]&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F[your_domain]`%2Ffb_connect%2F[domain_id]%2F&state=[some_hash]&scope=email
```

[your_app_id] = Facebook App Id
[your_domain] = www.domain.com or whatever your domain is
[domain_id]   = I used this to know from where the user came
[some_hash]   = used by Facebook to prevent xsrf

Then I had a little PHP-Script prepared to process the incoming data using apaches mod_rewrite

.htaccess in the fb_connect folder on my server

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

And in the index.php I used something like this

```
<?php

/* App-Id / Secret */
$sAppId     = '1234567890';
$sAppSecret = 'sdafuh347890oqtgfuasd';

/* Domains and IDs */
$aDomains = array(
    'www.domain.de' => 1,
    'www.domain-name.de' => 2,
     ...
);

/* Save a flipped copy */
$aFlip = array_flip($aDomains);

/* Save the request uri */
$sUri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

/* Explode the uri; facebook adds everything after the '?' */
$aParts = explode('?', $sUri);

/* Save the first part */
$sUri = $aParts[0];

/* Explode using slash */
$aParts = explode('/', $sUri);

/* This position should be the domain-id */
$iDomainId = $aParts[2];

/* get the domain name */
$sDomain = $aFlip[$iDomainId];

/* If the user authorizes the app this parameter is set */
if (!empty($_GET['code'])) {

    /*
     * The redirect uri is needed as a security parameter and needs to be EXACTLY
     * like in the refereing URI above
     */
    $sRedirectUri = 'http://www.domain.de/fb_connect/' . $iDomainId . '/';

    /* Get the access token url for the user */
    $sTokenUrl = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?'
       . 'client_id=' . $sAppId
       . '&client_secret=' . $sAppSecret
       . '&redirect_uri=' . urlencode($sRedirectUri)
       . '&code=' . $_GET['code'];

    /* Use CURL because file_get_contents() can't handle the length of the uri */
    $ch = curl_init();

    /* Url */
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $sTokenUrl);

    /* Header */
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

    /* Return the response instead of echoing it */
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    /* Exec the request */
    $sResponse = curl_exec($ch);

    /* close CURL */
    curl_close($ch);

    /* Initialize the Array for the returned data */
    $aParams = array();

    /* From the Facebook tutorial ;D */
    parse_str($sResponse, $aParams);

    /* Build the URI to query the opengraph with a user token */
    $sGraphUrl =
       'https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=' . $aParams['access_token'];

    /* get, decode and save the returned values */
    $aUser = (array)json_decode(file_get_contents($sGraphUrl));

    // You should now have the requested userdata and use it to create an account
    // or whatever ;D

    /* Redirect the user to the refering domain */
    header('Location: http://' . $sDomain);
    die;
}

/*
 * If the user doesn't authorize the app, this parameter is set.
 * Do whatever is needed here (logging, crying...) and redirect the user somewhere ;D
 */
if (!empty($_GET['error'])) {
    header('Location: http://' . $sDomain);
    die;
}

/*
 * If the user deletes the app using the control panel in facebook, your script will
 * recieve a ping containging this parameter. This is pretty much the same as if 
 * your app would run inside the facebook canvas.
 */
if (!empty($_POST['signed_request'])) {
    // Decode the signed request using the facebook tutorial methods, and delete
    // the user from your system :D
}

?>
```

This pretty much does the trick for me. If you have any questions feel free to ask.

Regards

Comment: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.