# Facebook authentication dialog - Passing data to the redirect_uri

Tags: facebook, parameter-passing, facebook-authentication

I am encountering a problem with passing data between pages that require facebook access.

Here is a simple example:
 Page 1 - has data ({str:"123"}) (but still didn't get the facebook access)
 Then it redirects to facebook_authentication which redirects to the redirect_uri (page 2)
 Page 2 - needs to get the data from page one, but it was interrupted by the facebook auth dialog.(page 2 needs the facebook access to submit the str data).

Is there any way I can pass the data from page one through the auth dialog to page 2?
Something like so: auth_url..parameters..?str=123
then i'll get it in page 2 like so $_GET['str'];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote an app that was running in facebook once and had to deal with this too. I used something like this

```
$sAppId = '12345567999455';

$sFBUrl = 'http://www.facebook.com/pages/<name>/<id>?sk=app_<app_id>&app_data=key:val;key:val';

$sDialogUrl = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=' . $sAppId . '&redirect_uri=' . urlencode($sFBUrl)

echo "<script>top.location.href='" . $sDialogUrl . "'</script>";
```

And then parsed the data

```
$aAppData = explode(';', $aSignedRequest['app_data']);
```

Which brings us to a solution for your case

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=app_id&redirect_uri=your_url?str=123
```

In my last app I used a trick I explained here: [SSO Website-Network with Facebook Login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10599778/sso-website-network-with-facebook-login/11013193#11013193)

Regards

Comment: But this url isn't the auth dialog, is it?

Comment: So your just appending a get parameter to the redirect_uri ... but isn't the redirect_uri supposed to be static? (facebook allows a specific one, doesn't it?)

Comment: Facebook keeps changeing the things you can do. Like i wrote in the answer to the other question I linked to you have to write a lot of workarounds to get facebook apps running.

In this case the url has to be static only for the initial request, and the following oauth_token request; so this should work.

Comment: Thanks, the get parameter works! But @mtariq also had a good idea, anyways, place the following url (in your answer) to explain the solution (that helped in my case) and i'll choose your answer as the solution:
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=app_id&redirect_uri=your_url?str=123

Comment: nice workaround, but this may break your application if facebook stop that and second it can cause security issue as you are passing your encrypted data to facebook.

Comment: @mtariq I agree with that. But facebook can be a real pain if you want it to work. Since we started building apps a few years ago the entire auth dialog has changed so much and so often that old apps simply won't work anymore. Even your suggestion to use cookies/sessions has it's limitations so I guess the app will have to be redesigned in a few months no matter what solution is chosen.

Answer (score 1):

The same problem we face during oAuth process implementation, The two possible solutions are

1. Save your data in cookie in page 1 and read the cookie in page 2.
2. Other solution is put the data in session.

I will advise to use 1 if it is user specific data.